# How to support .NET Framework 3.0 wpf application on the system that has only .NET Framework 4.0 & 4.5?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed an wpf application using .NET Framework 3.0, which runs perfectly on windows 7 system.

Now I want to support my application on windows 10 which supports from .NET Framework 4.0 onward. I have tried configuring app.config file to support .NET Framework 4., but it does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think it will work in 4.0 even if you don't have 3.0 installed. (not sure). Did you try this?

Comment: *but it does not work* Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but prompts for installation of 3.5

Comment: Any reason why your application can't just target .NET 4 or higher?

Comment: if your app targets version 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5, your users may be required to enable the .NET Framework 3.5 on a Windows 8 , Windows 8.1 and windows 10 computer before they can run your app.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, installing 3.5 solves the  problem. But 4.0 or 4.5 can supports 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5. My application has been hard coded to support only 3.0. I just need to know how  can i force it to run on 4.0 or 4.5 as well.

Comment: The app.config is broken. Is that intentional?

Comment: As @LexLi said, you need to close the `<startup>` tag before closing the `<configuration>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
<configuration>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> 
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" /> 
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Please refer to the following page on MSDN for more information about how to configure a .NET 3/3.5 application to support .NET 4+: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx